# WinJS gestureRecognizer - how to trap multiple gestures

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs, gesture-recognition

I've been using [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=842) article (and some others) to try and implement a gesture recognition in my app, and it does work.  However, what I want to do is to detect multiple gestures; for example, a swipe, and a touch.  What i don't seem to be able to do is to establish whether the `MouseUp` event is caused by the end of a gesture, or by a single touch.

```
function processUpEvent(e) {
    lastElement = e.currentTarget;
    gestureRecognizer.processUpEvent(e.currentPoint);

    processTouchEvent(e.currentPoint);
}
```

What happens currently is it processed both.  How can I detect whether the user has 'let go' of the screen for a swipe, or a touch?

EDIT:

```
    var recognizer = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();        

    recognizer.gestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationTranslateX
    recognizer.addEventListener('manipulationcompleted', function (e) {
        var dx = e.cumulative.translation.x
        //Do something with direction here
    });

    var processUp = function (args) {
        try {
            recognizer.processUpEvent(args.currentPoint);
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('MSPointerDown', function (args) {
        try {
            recognizer.processDownEvent(args.currentPoint);
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener('MSPointerMove', function (args) {
        try {
            recognizer.processMoveEvents(args.intermediatePoints);
        }
        catch (e) { } 
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('MSPointerUp', processUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('MSPointerCancel', processUp, false);
```

So I need to handle both `processUp` and `manipulationcompleted`, but one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do this, but it's not pretty:

```
var eventFlag = 0;

var processUp = function (args) {
    try {
        recognizer.processUpEvent(args.currentPoint);

        if (eventFlag == 0) {
           // do stuff
        } else {
           eventFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

recognizer.gestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationTranslateX
recognizer.addEventListener('manipulationcompleted', function (e) {
    var dx = e.cumulative.translation.x
    //Do something with direction here
    eventFlag = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my "input" demo in codeSHOW. Just install the codeSHOW app (http://aka.ms/codeshowapp) and look at the Pointer Input demo and "see the code" or just go to the [source code on CodePlex](https://codeshow.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21c26b4c0f7249e6d43e0300e1c9a8734a8f5516#codeSHOW/demos/input/input.js).
Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers my question.  Although this does cover dragging, I need to capture the direction.  I've updated my question with some more specific details.